# Alternative to global variables in app delegate

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an application with a speedometer like animation (a meter and an arrow to indicate something on the meter). I store the arrow's position in a global variable declared in my app delegate. I am doing it this way because the arrow position is updated and used by several classes.

However, I am insecure whether this is a good or a bad design decision. My thoughts are that since it is a non-critical piece of information (just a float), no harm is done when storing it globally. But my OOP heart hurts every time I say the word "global" to myself.

Alternatively I have studiet singletons, but as far as I have read, singletons are used when the developer wishes to create one and only one instance of a certain object.

Am I doing it correct or is there a more proper way of doing what I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am doing it this way because the arrow position is updated and used by several classes.

in many cases, you can reduce the scope. this reduces inter-component dependency.

> However, I am insecure whether this is a good or a bad design decision. My thoughts are that since it is a non-critical piece of information (just a float), no harm is done when storing it globally. But my OOP heart hurts every time I say the word "global" to myself.

perhaps you can move the state (the float value) to an ivar in your speedometer? example: you likely display just one speedometer view: does it make more sense to add it to what is the view's model? or perhaps to its controller? (yes, it's a bit tough to provide a more specific example without the source)

> Alternatively I have studiet singletons, but as far as I have read, singletons are used when the developer wishes to create one and only one instance of a certain object.

not necessary, and a severe pain to maintain. most of the cocoa singletons i have seen should not have been *considered* singletons, and caused a lot of headaches. better yet, you can write programs which use zero singletons. this is ideal, and easy to test. as is, the programs/types which depend on the app controller's have been compromised wrt testability and reusability.

> Am I doing it correct or is there a more proper way of doing what I do?

in the vast majority of cases, you can simply reduce the scope and localize it, while removing global state. with a little more effort, you can remove that value as a global -- that is best.

although it is not a good thing... let's assume you *really really really really really* must introduce global state:

- *don't* use a singleton. chances are good that you will rewrite it when you want to reuse it. it sugar coats what is ugly. if your app controller is a mess due to too much global state, at least the fact that you have too much global state will be obvious.
- hold your global state in your app controller. your app controller is responsible for its initialization, lifetime, and access.
- provide that state to dependencies, so they do not refer back to (or even know about) the global domain (the app controller). then you may minimize the impact.

there's also a distinct difference between global state and application/execution state. global state should be eliminated. execution state is not global state, but localized execution context. execution state can be reintroduced at the right level, altered, and updated, tested, and reused predictably. a good design will introduce execution state when needed, and at the right level while avoiding global state.

**Update**

Your sample is pretty close to what i had imagined, based on the description in the OP. It provided some additional specifics. So the sample below (you'll need some additions in obvious areas to piece it all together) demonstrates how you could update the controller interfaces, and there are two free 'elsewhere' methods at the end which further illustrate how to use these:

```
@interface MONArrowPosition : NSObject
{
    float arrowPosition;
}

@end

@implementation MONArrowPosition

- (id)initWithPosition:(float)position
{
    self = [super init];
    if (nil != self) {
        arrowPosition = position;
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@interface MyViewController1 : UIViewController
{
    MONArrowPosition * arrowPosition; // << may actually be held by the model
}

@end

@implementation MyViewController1

- (void)applyRotation
{
    [self rotateLayer:arrow from:self.arrowPosition to:callStatus speed:METER_SPEED];
}

@end

@interface MyViewController2 : UIViewController
{
    MONArrowPosition * arrowPosition; // << may actually be held by the model
}

@end

@implementation MyViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    /* ... */
    [self.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueDidChange) forControlEvents:controlEvents];
}

- (void)sliderValueDidChange
{
    self.arrowPosition.arrowPosition = self.slider.value;
    [self arrowPositionDidChange];
}

@end

/* elsewhere: */
- (void)initializeArrowPosition
{
    /* The variable is set to a default of 0.0f */
    MONArrowPosition * arrowPosition = [[MONArrowPosition alloc] initWithPosition:0.0f];
    /* ... */
}

- (IBAction)someActionWhichPushesMyViewController1
{
    // depending on the flow of your app, the body of initializeArrowPosition
    // *could* be right here
    MyViewController1 * viewController = [[MyViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle];
    viewController.arrowPosition = self.arrowPosition;
    /* push it */
}
```

and then if MyViewController1 pushes MyViewController2, locating and setting the arrow position will be easy. the view controllers may also be sharing some information in the models. with a global in your sample, you are crossing many implementations, which adds coupling, increases dependency, etc.. so if you can take this approach and localize the   execution state, you're off to a good start. then you can use any number of view controllers with any number of MONArrowPositions, and they will not be subject to the effects of global state. again, i can't get too specific using the samples provided, but i think this should illustrate the concepts i originally outlined well enough (i don't think a project-wide review is needed).

Comment: That was another point of view. I get your points, especially regarding the amount of extra work introduced using singletons. I dont have my source with me right now, but I will post some code later today so you can see exactly what my issue is about.

Comment: alright (if it makes sense to do so). some of the points i made could have helped how you approach the problem differently, and caused changes to your program. if instead, the approach works, it may be more helpful to describe what you did. if it didn't help, then some specifics could help solve your particular problem (i think the question is well formed, but not necessarily specific to your problem).

Comment: I have pasted my code with commens here: http://pastebin.com/HcmhN8q0 The thing is that it works very well on the simulator, but when I test it on my iPhone 4 (iOS 5 developer release), it crashes with a BAD_ACCESS exception when calling the rotate method.

Comment: As you can see above I decided to go for a pretty simple solution. However I am very interested in what you suggested and if you don't mind it would please me to hear what you have in mind regarding my code (see above). Thank you very much for your time anyway.

Comment: +1 for arguing in favor of AppDelegate vs singleton.  Singletons make it too easy to create more and more little bits of fractured global state (often redundant) without thinking about what you're doing.  The most important thing is to THINK about your global state and only make global those things that MUST be global.

Comment: Thanks again Justin. Your answer has put it in perspective and I will definitely be using your sample code at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is something that is keeping a lot of programmers up at night.

I try not to misuse the app delegate as much, I'll create a singleton for storing more or less global information. There is no real other way to do it then either the singleton or the app delegate.

But if only one viewController need the information than, the information will never leave that viewController. That viewcontroller could pass that information on to other viewcontroller is needed.

In you case it might be an idea to have some kind of directionManager which hold the floats and might even hold the CLLocationManager.

Comment: Okay, so you suggest to store a CLLocationManager with the coordinates in a singleton class instead of just making the variables global? I have googled directionManager, but with no luck. Could you explain that any further?

Comment: directionManager is just a suggestion for the name of the singleton that you could create.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, rckoenes. I will consider a re-design of my app's data sharing.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of thing, I like to use NSNotifications.  You have all the view controllers who care about the arrow's position listen for the specific notification, and they can all update the UI at once.

Comment: It's a pretty simple application I am dealing with and using NSNotifications combined with NSUserDefaults did the trick for me. Thanks for the tip.