# Objective-C Alternative to using ApplicationDelegate or singleton to pass data

Tags: objective-c, dependency-injection, singleton, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm working on an exiting iOS app (called Mazin in the App store, if anyone is interested) and I'm trying to rework the code to avoid using the Application Delegate or a singleton for sharing information/methods.  In particular I have the following to share across certain views and controllers:

- CoreData objects like NSManagedObjectConttext and related custom methods for interacting with the data
- State properties used in several places like currentMazeType, gameMode, and soundIsMuted along with a few widely used utility methods particular to the game
- Views and methods used to display information used commonly throughout the app (e.g., an ActivityIndicator and methods to show/hide it on a given view)

In general, several views and ViewControllers need access to various subsets of this information and I need a mechanism to share the information and methods "globally" across these objects.  Some of this sharing is for convenience (e.g., every time I want to display a basic activity indicator, I just  call a common "startActivityIndicator" method) but some are required (e.g., changing gameMode changes it "globally" and several views/controllers need to access the common mode info).

What sort of patterns would work best for this requirement?  I have my own solution in mind, and I'll post it below for your consideration/comments.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to post my own answer until 8 hours after I've posted my question, but I'll post it in the morning.  In general, I could create utility classes to hold the common data/methods, let the Application Delegate make the one and only instance of each utility class, and let the delegate then pass them (like dependencies) to appropriate member objects (who would pass them as dependencies to their child objects, and so on).  More detail when I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution I am considering:

I plan to create a few "utility" classes (e.g. GameDataUtil, AppStateUtil, GadgetsUtil) that each encapsulate a proper subset of the "global" information and/or methods.  Each View or ViewController that needs to access the common info/methods in a utility will have an appropriate property of that given type (e.g., a view that can make a sound needs access to the AppStateUtil so it can determine if sounds are currently muted).

The ApplicationDelegate will be the only class that generates single instances of the "utility" classes and will pass those instances to the appropriate objects that get loaded from its Nib (in applicationDidFinishLaunching).  Those views/controllers will have to pass all necessary information to any of their members that they may load programmatically (which could get hairy--class A may need a GagetsUtil in order to pass it to an instance of class B even though class A never uses the utility directly).

This is sort of like injecting dependencies from the application delegate down (since I don't have the utility of an Dependency Injection Container).

Now, I have thought about creating an uber-utility (e.g., ConfigUtil) that would hold one property for each of the other utilities.  The AppDelegate would create a single instance of the uber-utility (setting it up with instances of the other utilities it creates).  The AppDelegate would pass the uber-utility instance to anyone who needs access to any of the basic utilities.  Each basic utility would still encapsulate a sub-set of the common data/methods, but by putting one of each into an uber-utility and passing it around, I don't have to keep up with which utility is needed by which class (not only for its own use but also to pass to any of its member objects).

Comment: Seriously?  I've seen just the opposite suggested in other posts--don't answer your own question in an edit because then you're not asking a question, you're asking for comments.  I asked my question and hope others will suggest solutions.  This is my current thinking on a solution and others can comment or offer a totally different answer.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  Thanks for the comment.  I was looking at it as a solution (e.g., if someone comes and reads my question, finds it useful to their situation, and then wants to look down at solutions, my post here is possibly a solution).  BUT I am looking for feedback as well--so I can see where an edit might also be appropriate.

Comment: @FTLPhysicsGuy I now remember having detailed a means to reflow the program in another answer here at SO -- The link's in my updated answer.

Comment: Saw the link.  Nice reply on the other thread--I plussed it up.

Comment: Here's a dependency injection container: https://github.com/jasperblues/spring-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

`NSNotification` would be a step away from that model, and is typically easy to implement.

If many things know of and refer to mutable global data right now... it will take time to undo that.

**Update**

I remembered that I had written [a more detailed response to a similar scenario here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635008/alternative-to-global-variables-in-app-delegate/7635786#7635786).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I use Notifications in the app--typically to notify the controllers when the model changes--and I suppose it's a reasonable solution if an object needs to take action when, say, a setting changes.  However, if a controller needs to change the setting itself, it obviously needs more direct access.  Also, if the controller does not need to take action when the change occurs but will need to know the current value of the setting at some point in the future, a notification might not be the right answer.